# Rails 3 Named Route with Segment Key "No route matches" Search Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm getting a "No route matches" error when calling search_path in my search_field_tag. The search form is in my header, the idea is simply to be able to do searches on events.

Here is the route in routes.rb:

```
match '/events/search/:query' => 'events#search', :as => "search"
```

Here is the code for the search form.

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => :get do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
    <%= submit_tag "search", :name => :nil %>
<% end %>
```

(How to make sure when I submit this form that it will submit to /events/search/:query? :query being the value in the search_field_tag)

Here is the code in my events_controller

```
def search 
      @search_q = params[:query]
      @events = Event.search @search_q #uses thinking sphinx

      respond_with @events
  end
```

I also have created /views/events/search.html.erb

I'm pretty sure the error is coming from the line in the search form where I say search_path. Everything else seems to work exactly as I expect it to, though, for example, if I visit /events/search/someterm it works exactly as I expect it to. It's just a matter of plugging in the search form and submitting to events#search. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: search        /events/search/:query(.:format)                     {:action=>"search", :controller=>"events"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that query is being passed as a post request. Your route is looking for:

```
/events/search
```

where as you defined:

```
/events/search/:query
```

So just drop the /:query at the end of your route. The query is passed as params on post. No need to have it in the routes.

Comment: thanks for the response. i updated my route as you suggested but now there are new problems: Couldn't find Event with id=search. clearly it now thinks that search is the :id in /events/search. also i can see that the show action is being called.

Comment: i've also updated my code above to show that i'm explicitly calling :method => :get.

Comment: make sure that your search route is above the event resources. Routes get run in order, so if the events/:id route is first then it will try to look for an event with an ID of search and return an error.

Comment: Also, POST is the correct method for search, but you should just use "match", either way. Or you can leave it on GET and change your form method to GET.